# Rails: fastest function to extract json field and convert to array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, json

I have a json object as follows which is the input.

```
[
{"feild1":"val11","field2":"val12"},
{"feild1":"val21","field2":"val22"},
{"feild1":"val31","field2":"val32"}
]
```

I want output in an array object **for only feild1**, as follows:

```
array_for_feild_one =  ["val11", "val21", "val31"]
```

I know I can loop through the whole json object, but then I don't see the point of JSON object, whats the use of keys and values when I have to use a loop in the end, isn't there a better way ?

So far I have tried this:

```
json_obj.each do |obj|

    my_array << obj['field1']
end
```

**edit:**

Complete code is as follows:

```
json_obj = JSON.parse('[
{"feild1":"val11","field2":"val12"},
{"feild1":"val21","field2":"val22"},
{"feild1":"val31","field2":"val32"}
]')
my_array = []
json_obj.each do |obj| 
        my_array << obj['field1']
end
puts my_array.inspect
```

Comment: you can try as `json_obj.collect{|a| a["feild1"]}`

Comment: thanks, it worked.. any more alternatives?

Comment: yes there are many iterators available in ruby like `map`,`collect` you can also used this

Answer (score 1):

you can try following way using `collect` method in ruby:

```
json_obj = JSON.parse('[
{"feild1":"val11","field2":"val12"},
{"feild1":"val21","field2":"val22"},
{"feild1":"val31","field2":"val32"}
]')
my_array = json_obj.collect{|a| a["feild1"]}
puts my_array.inspect
```

Answer (score 1):

There is an alternate way you can do it in single line of code ;)

```
ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(your_json).map{|a| a["feild1"]}
```